# How to return result of test-connection from if statement?

Tags: powershell, variables

I have solution but it looks ugly. 
here is my cutted code

```
$Output= @()
$hosts = hosts.txt
foreach ($name in $hosts){
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
   $Output+= Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  }
}
$Output | Out-file result.txt
```

Is there any default variable containing result of Test-connection ?
I want to write something like $Output+= $result

Answer (score 0):

This is a typo: "$hosts = hosts.txt".  I would do:

```
Get-Content hosts.txt | Test-Connection| Export-Csv result.csv
```

Comment: Why have you exported the result to a csv?

Comment: @WasifHasan person preference, I can import it back later into objects

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the content of the file using Get-Content.

```
$Output= @()
$hosts = Get-Content hosts.txt
foreach ($name in $hosts){
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
   $Output+= Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  }
}
$Output | Out-file result.txt
```